# Reversing cumulative sum to determine actuals in R

Tags: r, cumsum

I have a df where each row is the cumulative sum of the row above it. Is there a way to derive the original values from this df?

```
   X1 X2
1  1  5
2  3  9
3  6 12
4 10 14
5 15 15
```

Desired output:

```
   X1 X2
1  1  5
2  2  4
3  3  3
4  4  2
5  5  1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `diff`. Assuming your dataset is called "mydf" and you want to do this for all columns, try:

```
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, function(x) diff(c(0, x)))
mydf
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  5
# 2  2  4
# 3  3  3
# 4  4  2
# 5  5  1
```

Since `diff` returns a vector of `length` one less than the input, you need to pad the input with a `0` (thus also retaining the original value in that column).

---

As @DavidArenburg mentions, you could also easily adapt this to "data.table" code too, like this:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) diff(c(0, x)))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(.-c(0,lag(.)[-1])))
 #  X1 X2
 #1  1  5
 #2  2  4
 #3  3  3
 #4  4  2
 #5  5  1
```

Or as @BrennanBeal mentioned in the comments, in the recent versions of `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(X1:X2), ~ .-c(0,lag(.)[-1]))
```

Or from `dplyr` 1.0.0

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(X1:X2, ~ .-c(0,lag(.)[-1])))
```

Comment: Recently found this (and used a modified version) so thanks for posting! Coming here much later, mutate_each is deprecated and the code now needs:

`df %>% mutate_at(vars(X1:X2),funs(.-c(0,lag(.)[-1])))`

Hopefully this helps someone in the future and thanks for your post.

Comment: @BrennanBeal thank you.  I added your comments in the post.  Hope you don't mind. thanks